# How create a simple get form that will create a dynamic route, depending on the value of the search field (MONGODB and Node.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

i want search throw the database for a value that the user puts in a get form.

The backend is very simple, i know how to search throw the database and render the result..

```
app.get('search/:id', function(req, res) {
  var id  = req.param("id");

  mongoose.model('Something').find({
     // the field that i want find. For example:
      _id: id // This will search for the id field in the database, them will return a object if finds a match.
  }, function(error, object){
        if (error) {
          res.send(error);
        }
        else {
          res.send(object);
        }
     }
  );
});
```

This script will work.

Now i'm having problems with the HTML.

I need a get form that will send a user to /search/SOMETHING THAT THE USER WANTS SEARCH, but i don't know exactly how to change the url dinamically..

Any help is very very welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't know how to achieve desired behaviour in the HTML, you could still do it in the backend - by setting a redirect. Your incoming request after form submission would be something like `?inputName=user search string`.

You could then take the value of the query and perform an internal redirect to your route

```
app.get('search', function(req, res) {
  res.redirect('/search/' + req.query["inputName"]);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

to get a form to pass GET params in a nice express-like way, you need to hook on the onSubmit of the form and then trigger an XHR/ajax request instead of the form-post.

Or you can read the querystring via `req.query.inputFieldName` if you are okay having the url look like `/search/?inputFieldName=AwesomeSearchString`

I'd take the XHR/ajax way as it also prevents the page from reloading and thus improving user-experience.